# Calculating overall total column for each row in a table with dynamic SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dynamic-sql

I have the following tables:
[image]

And I would like to query a table to show total payment based on location (which has dynamic values) for every user + the overall total as follow:
[image]

I was able to get it up to the breaking into locations point, the only thing that I could not get is the Total column, here is my SQL:

```
    USE fypdb;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN attendance.location_id=''', attendance.location_id,''' then 
    FORMAT(position.pay_rate*TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(attendance.logout_time, attendance.login_time))/3600, 2) else 0 end) AS `',
    location.name,'`') 
) INTO @sql FROM attendance JOIN location ON attendance.location_id = location.location_id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user.user_name,', @sql, '
                 SUM(FORMAT(position.pay_rate*TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(attendance.logout_time, attendance.login_time))/3600, 2)) AS Total ',        #this is the problematic attribute 
                 'FROM attendance 
                 JOIN user ON attendance.user_id = user.user_id
                 JOIN position ON user.position_id = position.position_id
                    GROUP BY attendance.user_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

As per above, if I remove the problematic attribute (total) the commands works fine, but when I try to get the total I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(FORMAT(position.pay_rate*TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(attendance.logout_time, attend' at line 4
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Note: I am using MySQL version 5.7.9

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you use concatenation and you are missing space after Total in problematic line. next line 'FROM has no space so resulting query is
`AS TotalFROM` instead of `AS Total FROM`

Comment: That's correct, I modified that, but the error is still the same.